# Rails create profile after sign up in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i have installed devise in my app and now i want to create profile just after the individual(user) signed up and redirect them to the profile page

here is my individual model

```
class Individual < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

my profile model is

```
  class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :individual
      before_create :build_profile
 def completed_profile?
    self.first_name.present? && self.last_name.present? && self.address_line_1.present? && self.city.present? && self.state.present? && self.zipcode.present?
  end
    end
```

Migration file for profile is

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :individual, index: true
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :age
      t.string :birth_date
      t.string :gender
      t.string :bio
      t.string :linkedin_profile
      t.string :facebook_profile
      t.string :twitter_profile
      t.integer :mobile_no

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

and my profiles controller is given as

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_individual!
    before_action :find_profile, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    respond_to :html

    def index
      @profiles = Profile.all
    end

    def new
      @profile = current_individual.build_profile
    end

    def create
      @profile = current_individual.build_profile(profile_params)
      if @profile.save
        flash[:success] = "Profile saved"
        redirect_to current_individual_path
      else
        flash[:error] = "Error"
        render :new
      end
    end

    def show
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
      @profile.update(profile_params)
      respond_with(@profile)
    end


    private

    def find_profile
      @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
    end

    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :birth_date,
                                      :gender, :bio, :personal_website, :linkedin_profile, :facebook_profile,
                                      :mobile_no, :telephone_no)
    end
  end
```

and i have the routes as

```
devise_for :individuals
```

my application controller has

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_individual.completed_profile?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      redirect_to edit_individual_profile_path
    end
  end
end
```

please tell me how can the user will be signed up and after signing in they would be redirected to profile's edit view where the individual can edit the profile 
Thank you !!

Comment: So will the profile be incomplete initially? Because you will need some condition when should the user get redirected.

Comment: yes the same way facebook uses when the user signs up they would be taken to the profile's edit page , that means the profile has been created automatically when the user signed up

Comment: Take a look at this Devise howto: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)

Comment: Check the code now and make changes accordingly your main error has been resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are creating a new profile when the individual is saved so what you can do is you can create a method named `completed_profile`. So for this in your `individual` model you can do is create a instance method:

```
def completed_profile?
  self.first_name.present? && self.last_name.present? && self.address_line_1.present? && self.city.present? && self.state.present? && self.zipcode.present?
end
```

And in your application controller you can define this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  redirect_to edit_individual_profile_path unless current_individual.profile.completed_profile?
end
```

Source: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in-and-sign-out

So when the user will `sign_in` each time it will be redirected to edit profile page if his profile is not completed.

Modify the code according to you needs this is extracted from my application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is showing
NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
undefined method `first_name' for #<Individual:0xa015c20>
but the first_name is the method of profile and i have included that in profiles controller

Comment: So did you call it like `current_individual.profile.complete_profile?` ? And why is it showing `Devise::RegistrationsController#create` where have you inserted this code and how?

Comment: And the `after_sign_in_path_for` should go either in `application_controller` or devise controllers if you have overrided them.

Comment: same error if i override in the registration controller

Comment: i put after_sign_in_path_for(resource) in application controller in first try and in registration controller in the next try and completed_profile? method in individual model

Comment: Post the code what you have done till now and where have you posted the above code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84298/discussion-between-codeprotocol-and-deep).